# Can I use Processing 2.1 without installing the Android SDK?

Tags: processing

I am visiting someone with excruciatingly slow Internet and had downloaded the 64-bit 2.1 version of Processing from [here](http://processing.org/download/?processing) before leaving home. I have unzipped the file, but when I try to open it I get the following message:

> **Is the Android SDK installed?**
>   The Android SDK does not appear to be installed, because the ANDROID_SDK variable is not set.  If it is installed, click "Yes" to select the location of the SDK, or "No" to visit the SDK download site at http://developer.android.com/sdk.

If I were at home I would download this and be on my merry way, but at almost half a gigabyte this is going to be about a 5 hour download assuming the connection holds.

I have a sketch from my desktop I moved over to the laptop and I just want to run it locally, but is it even possible to use Processing without the Android SDK?  Searches so far have only shown me ways to troubleshoot actually installing it.

Comment: try http://sketch.openprocessing.org/sketch/create that should work on most slow connections..

Comment: ideally I could take this with me in the car and ultimately use without any Internet connection.

Comment: Am I perhaps not asking the right question here?  If the answer is you have to install the SDK that's fine, but would be nice to know.

Comment: I think it's "install JRE first", sec, will run check on it. As for place, it's definitely ok to ask about selecting proper runtime here - for Java, it's more like here than on superuser.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, running 'processing.exe' from Processing 2.1 does not require Android SDK or JDK.
Are you on Linux?

Comment: I am on Windows on my laptop.  I will try re-installing when I get home on a more stable connection.